# Prove $\forall \epsilon\ \exists \delta\ \forall x \ \ |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<g(\epsilon)$ implies $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that
$$\forall \epsilon\ \exists \delta\ \forall x \ \ |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<g(\epsilon)\tag{1}$$
where $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to 0+}g(y)=0$ and $g(y) > 0$, implies that
$$\forall \epsilon\ \exists \delta\ \forall x \ \ |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon\tag{2}$$

I'm a bit confused concerning the dependencies between the different variables and limits. It seems to me there could be up to three epsilons involved, or only one that one carries from one limit to another. We have:

Let $\epsilon$ be given. Then $\exists \delta = |x - x_0| \rightarrow |f(x) - L| < g(\epsilon)$
Let $\zeta>0$ be given. Then $\exists \gamma> 0$ s.t. $y < \gamma \rightarrow g(y) < \zeta$

But how do we get to say $y = \epsilon$? And furthermore, once we get to say $y = \epsilon$, how do we get it to be less than $\gamma$? Any help, or reading suggestions, is highly appreciated!

Comment: Choose  $ \epsilon < \gamma$ in $(1)$, then $g( \epsilon)< \zeta$

Comment: @Student hm, do we suppose $\gamma$ is given before $\epsilon$? thanks for the response by the way

Comment: Take $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily. Find $\delta_1>0$ such that $0<g(x)<\epsilon$ for any $x$ belonging to $(0,\delta_1).$ Now find $\delta_2>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-L|<g(\delta_1/2)$. Since $\delta_1/2$ belongs to $(0,\delta_1)$ we have $0<g(\delta_1/2)<\epsilon$ and so $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for any $x\in (x_0-\delta_2,x_0+\delta_2)$.

Comment: Can you make use of $\forall \epsilon\ \exists \delta'\ \forall y>0 \ \ |y-0|<\delta'\Rightarrow |g(y)-0|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @shintuku continue your answer "Let $\zeta>0$ be given. Then $\exists \gamma> 0$ s.t. $y < \gamma \rightarrow g(y) < \zeta$". Since $(1)$ is true then we can choose $\epsilon< \gamma$, then $g( \epsilon )< \zeta$, now if $|x-x_{0}|< \delta$ (the existence of delta follows from $(1)$) then $|f(x)-L|<g(\epsilon)< \zeta$.

Comment: ahh, thanks to you all for the clarifications! very appreciated!